# On button click reload a php pull from mysql database without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've got a .php page where I display table from MySQL database using PHP based on cookie value.

On this page, without page reload I'm able to change cookie data with a button click:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $(".button").click(function () {
        Cookies.remove('cookie');
        Cookies.set('cookie', 'value', { expires: 7 });

    });

});
```

How to refresh mysql SELECT in the same click functionality so the data inside table reloads without page reloading?

I've got my php data in:

`<div id="refresh-table">
<?php include 'pull-from.php'; ?>
</div>`

I have read all over the place I have to use AJAX - but I cannot set it up according to all posts i've been through. I would really appriciate your support.

Comment: add `$.get('pull-from.php', function(data) { $('#refresh-table').html(data); }`, basically

Comment: Got it! thank you SO MUCH! I waste like 3 hours. But learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some code to your pull-from.php file  (or create another file that uses it to get the data) that can accept parameters from the AJAX call and return a response, preferably JSON. This is basically your web service.

Below is a barebones example of what the php basically needs to do.  i included an html page that fetches data from the web service and displays it.

```
<?php
$criteria = $_POST['criteria'];

function getData($params) {
    //Call MySQL queries from here, this example returns static data, rows      simulate tabular records.

    $row1 = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
    $row2 = array('foo1', 'bar1', 'baz1');
    $row3 = array('foo2', 'bar2', 'baz2');

    if ($params) {//simulate criteria actually selecting data
        $data = array(
            'rows' => array($row1, $row2, $row3)
        );

    }
    else {
        $data = array();
    }

    return $data;
}

$payload = getData($criteria);

header('Content-Type: application/json');//Set header to tell the browser what sort of response is coming back, do not output anything before the header is set.
echo json_encode($payload);//print the response 
?>
```

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Sample PHP Web Service</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("Lets get started, data from the web service should appear below when you close this.");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'web-service.php',
        data: {criteria: 42},//values your api needs to query data
        method: 'POST',
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);//display data in done callback
        $('#content').html(
        JSON.stringify(data.rows)//I just added the raw data
        );
    });

});
```

Comment: I have went over the code, implemented and works like a charm. This is stuff I need to go through more. Much appreciated for helping here.